# Free trial period for iOS non-subscription apps

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple just modified their iOS App Store guidelines to allow a free trial period for non-subscription paid apps. The guidelines indicate that the free trial period is provided by a 0-tier in-app purchase with a name in the form "XX-day Trial".

When the app launches, does this mean you should immediately put up a modal dialog to offer the free trial IAP?

Comment: Apple has as always chosen the most complicated route possible to implement an inherently simple thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question,

They did **NOTHING** on the SDK side. All they did is change the Appstore guidelines. You as a developer are responsible for handling all the aspects.

> how and when do you present the user with the option for starting the
>   trial? Is this a modal dialog presented on opening the app?

On you to decide, but I advise you to do that as soon as user start the App to eliminate any misunderstandings.

> how do you interact with the user when the trial has expired? Another
>   modal dialog?

The same as the first one :(

> how is the app represented in the app store? It is a paid app but has
>   an initial price of 0. How does this work?

It's free (which in my opinion is really bad since a user assuming that your app is free and may get frustrated when finding out that it's actually not. Also, that removes the possibility to sell app witch discount for 500, and etc copies for as bulk sell.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that Apple requires that your app needs to have some functionality without the IAP. The IAP is used to unlock additional/full features.

For example, a free video editor might allow you to create 1 minute clips with an IAP to remove this limit.

You can use a 0 cost IAP to provide a free trial of full functionality.

In this case it might make sense to present the purchase dialog when the user tries to make a video clip longer than a minute.

If the free trial has never been used, you offer the chance to trial for 7 days or whatever by purchasing the free trial or unlock forever by purchasing the regular unlock.

If the free trial has already been used, then you would only offer the paid unlock.

At the end of the free trial the app would revert to the original, limited, functionality.

You should not simply prompt the user to purchase the trial the first time the app is launched and the app cannot be non-functional without the IAP.

If you want the app to not function at all without payment then you should probably release a paid app, not a free app.

Comment: Why does the app need functionality without the IAP? I can see how putting a video here might be useful for advertising the app, but wouldn't an initial modal dialogue offering the free trial and the actual purchase also be appropriate? Just wondering about your reasoning...

Comment: Well, it is just my opinion but Apple have a "minimum functionality" guideline. If the app does nothing without the purchase they might reject it. They might not

Comment: EveryCircuit for iOS will only work if you register at their server and offers a 24hour free test period after registration. After that, the app locks and you cannot even see the projects you have created.